# Square inside of an isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

There is an isosceles triangle with base $a=10$ and sides $b=13$. A square is inscribed inside of this triangle such that two of it's vertices are touching base and two of them are touching sides. What is the length of a side of the square?

The solution is $60/11$, but I don't know how to arrive at it.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on this question? Please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2784043/edit) to add something more than a bare problem statement.

Comment: No. I know what the answer is, but I don't know how to arrive at it. Actually, I'll edit the question and write the answer.

Comment: There are many possibilities. One more condition is needed.. like maximum area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the isoceles triangle be denoted by $\Delta ABC$, with the vertex at point $B$. Let the square be denoted by $\square DEFG$, with the vertices $D,E$ lying on the sides of the triangle and the vertices $F,G$ lying on the base. Let $r$ denote the length of the side of the square.

Note that $\Delta ABC$ is similar to $\Delta DBE$, so since the height of $\Delta ABC$ is $12$ and the height of $\Delta DBE$ is $12 - r$, we have
$$\frac{r}{10} = \frac{12-r}{12}.$$
Solving for $r$ gives $r = 12\cdot 10/22 = 60/11$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use that $$\frac{x}{10}=\frac{h-x}{h}$$ where $h$ is the hight of the given triangle and $x$ is the side length of the square.